# title on polyline map makers is not show if is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have tried adding title on polyline map makers, but it doesn't work for me. I do not understand what has gone wrong or why it does not work correctly.
I've tried adding title, or description, but can't get it to work.
It does not give me errors in console, but title does not appear if I click on it.

```
      function initialize() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: { lat: 42.9994443, lng: -0.0107599},
      zoom: 12
    });

    var fromMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: { lat: 43.1002647, lng: -0.0423151 },
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });

    var toMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: { lat: 42.8906, lng: -0.115006 },
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });

    var ds = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    ds.route({
      origin: fromMarker.getPosition(),
      destination: toMarker.getPosition(),
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    }, function (result, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        console.log(result);

        new google.maps.Polyline({
          map: map,
          path: result.routes[0].overview_path,


                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                geodesic: true,
                icons: [{
                    icon: {path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW},
                    offset: '100%',
                    repeat: '40px'
                }]
        });

        var fullPath = [];

        result.routes[0].legs.forEach(function (leg) {
          leg.steps.forEach(function (step) {
            fullPath = fullPath.concat(step.path);
            new google.maps.Polyline({
              map: map,
              path: step.path,
              strokeColor: "red",
              strokeWeight: 1
            });
          });
        });


      }
    });

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: `title` sets the tooltip/mouseover text for the marker.  Clicking the marker doesn't effect it.  Are you looking for an `InfoWindow` to open on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marker title is shown on hover. If you want to show info window on click you should add something like the following:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<span>Your title</span>"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(fromMarker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, fromMarker);
});
```

More information about Info Windows: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: if i need to put 2 destination. How can I put each one a different infowindows?

Comment: just create one more infowindow object and bind it to the other marker.